# LDAP Configuration in Openfire Issue : NullPointerException

Tags: ldap

Below is my OpenLDAP structure :

> +--> dc=test,dc=com (3)
>   ---> cn=admin
>   +--> ou=groups (3) | ---> cn=admin | ---> cn=irc | ---> cn=users | ---> Create new entry here
>   +--> ou=users (4) | ---> cn=user1 | ---> cn=user2 | ---> cn=user3 | ---> cn=user4

The setttings in Openfire :
Step 1 :
Port : 389
Base DN : ou=users,dc=test,dc=com
Administrator DN: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com

Step 2 :User Mapping :
Username Field:uid

Step 3: Group Mapping
Group Field:cn
Member Field:uniqueMember
Description Field: description

For the next window when I am clicking on Save and Continue, I get following exception :

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /setup/setup-admin-settings.jsp. Reason:

```
Server Error
```

Caused by:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>             at org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.setup.setup_002dadmin_002dsettings_jsp._jspService(setup_002dadmin_002dsettings_jsp.java:99)
>             at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
>             at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:547)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1359)
>             at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
>             at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
>             at org.jivesoftware.util.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:74)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
>             at org.jivesoftware.util.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:50)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
>             at org.jivesoftware.admin.PluginFilter.doFilter(PluginFilter.java:78)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
>             at org.jivesoftware.admin.AuthCheckFilter.doFilter(AuthCheckFilter.java:164)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1330)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:478)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:941)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:409)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:875)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:441)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:919)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:582)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)

Also I did some changes and I was able to see the Add Administrator screen but I was not able to add any of my existing LDAP users here. It was  throws following error :

"No username was provided or the specified username was not found."

I restarted the server and since then NullPointerException started coming back again.- (well that deserves another discussion, once I get through this)

Where am I going wrong?

FYI, both the servers, openfire and OpenLdap, are running on same virtual machines.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: I could proceed to the next screen by changing advanced settings in user mapping section. My changes are :

Posix Mode: No

Group Filter : (objectClass=Group)

But now I am facing the another issue, I mentioned earlier :

---- I was not able to add any of my existing LDAP users here. It was throws following error :

"No username was provided or the specified username was not found."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could proceed to the next screen by changing advanced settings in user mapping section. My changes are : Posix Mode: No Group Filter : (objectClass=Group)

Surprisingly, once I reached to the Add Administrator screen, after coming back I reset these fields and it was still working fine. I wonder if after restarting the server it will work or not.

Also in the Step 1, make sure in the hostname you provide the ip address of your machine. With localhost it dint work for me.

Thanks,
Hope it helps anyways!

Answer (score 0):

For the other query I had, I could add administrators by modifying my Base DN to "Base DN : dc=test,dc=com"
With specifying ou, it seems I was restricting the users.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have that problem even all the test were successfull (by clicking the "Test" buttons you have next to the "Save and continue" button), it is because it took you too long to finalize the setup and the session somehow expired.

Restart the `openfire` service, reload the web page and go through the setup process again, in one go.